# Unity C# UI.Text issue: (...) This is not supported. UnityEngine.Canvas:SendWillRenderCanvases()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Trying to add `LineDescriptor(Clone)` (`UnityEngine.UI.Text`) for graphic rebuild while we are already inside a graphic rebuild loop. This is not supported. `UnityEngine.Canvas:SendWillRenderCanvases()`

Hey, I get that issue when I try to update positions of many game objects with Text Component attached. Have any idea what's the reason of that bug?

```
  for(int i = 0; i< dottedLines.Count; i++)
    {
        dottedLineStaff[dottedLines[i]][1].transform.position = RectTransformUtility.WorldToScreenPoint(Camera.main, dottedLineStaff[dottedLines[i]][0].transform.position);
    }
```

Comment: I've solved that. I had problem with sharing the same references for many objects. In short: I tried to save every Text object using one pre-made reference and instead of getting bug "null reference", I got that one. Every time when I saved new Text object, the old one lost its reference.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when I had an asynchronous plugin controlling a script that instantiates UI prefabs. Basically the plugin would occasionally instantiate a UI prefab during the Graphic.Rebuild loop. Parts of the UI prefab would draw incorrectly until I interacted with them.

My solution was to queue the instantiations for the next Update() call instead of instantiating them exactly when the plugin invoked a callback. Something similar to:

```
List<string> queue = new List<string>();
private object thisLock = new object();

public void PluginCallback(string name)
{
    // instead of instantiating/modifying UI elements here, queue them for later
    lock (thisLock)
    {
        queue.Add(name);
    }
}

void Update()
{
    lock (thisLock)
    {
        // shouldn't be in a Graphic.Rebuild loop now
        if (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string name in queue)
            {
                Text text = (Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject).GetComponent<Text>();
                text.text = name;
            }
            queue.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Just FYI - I've also seen other posts where the issue was more likely a Unity bug (iOS, older Unity versions, etc.).

EDIT: added locking to example (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx). I'm pretty new to the concepts this issue involves, so I may be evolving my answer over time ... so, I give no claim to the example's general appropriateness overall - I'm only saying that in my case it resolved the errors the OP describes.